# PCI Passthrough Error

Tags: virtualbox, pci

I am following [this article](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough) to do a PCI passthrough, but I get the following error message.

```
$ VBoxManage modifyvm 'Windows 10 VM' --pciattach 1d:00.0
VBoxManage: error: Host PCI attachment only supported with ICH9 chipset
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "AttachHostPCIDevice(iHostAddr, iGuestAddr, TRUE)" at line 3142 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

So, I changed my virtualbox chipset to ICH9, but now when I try to start my VM it gives me an error

[image: Image 1]

Comment: Do you have the Extension Pack installed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not have it installed, but I just installed it, then I switched the vhipset to ICH9 and tried again to run the modifyvm command and got this error message:VBoxManage: error message:        Device with host PCI address already attached to this VM
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "AttachHostPCIDevice(iHostAddr, iGuestAddr, TRUE)" at line 3142 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp

Comment: It may mean that whatever you're trying to use in the VM can't be used because it's needed for the host. For example, you need to have 2 graphics cards if you want to use the passthrough of one of them, can't be done with only one or hybrid graphics in a laptop.

Comment: Thank you, Gabriela. I think maybe VirtualBox doesn't support the chipset, so I will upgrade to VMWare. Thanks again.